# Firebase asynchronous database

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, promise

In this code I want to get the `posSnapshot.val().case` and store it in the `tatarget` var, for this I need to execute the `dbCall()` function BEFORE `console.log('TARGETOUT', tatarget)`

```
function dbCall() {

    var toReturn;

    return admin.database().ref().child('games/' + event.params.gameId + '/player1/boats').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function(typeSnapshot) {

            typeSnapshot.forEach(function(posSnapshot) {

                console.log('POSKEY', posSnapshot.key);

                if(posSnapshot.key != 'status') {

                    console.log(rngPos, incr, posSnapshot.val().state);

                    if(rngPos == incr && posSnapshot.val().state == 0) {

                        console.log('===');

                        return(posSnapshot.val().case);
                    }
                    else if(rngPos == incr && posSnapshot.val().state == 1) {

                        return('1');
                    }

                    incr ++;
                }
            });
        });
    });
} 

var loopPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    DD = dbCall();

    tatarget = DD.then(function(dbResult) {

        console.log(dbResult);

        return dbResult;
    });

    console.log('TARGETOUT', tatarget);

    console.log('TARGETRESOLVE', tatarget);

    resolve(tatarget);
});

loopPromise.then(function(loopResult) {

    console.log(loopResult);
});
```

My problem is that the `dbCall()` function end AFTER the `console.log` !

I tried every promise, every callback functions, I also tried `async` and `await` but Firebase don't handle it.

I worked to this part of code for more than 15 hours.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could always be organized better but basically you:

1. Return the `Firebase ref` promise from `dbCall()`
2. Wait for the promise with `then()`
3. Perform your desired functionality
4. `resolve` your promise, because `loopPromise` is a promise

---

```
function dbCall() {

    var toReturn;

    return admin.database().ref().child('games/' + event.params.gameId + '/player1/boats').once('value');
} 

var loopPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    dbCall().then(function(snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function(typeSnapshot) {

            typeSnapshot.forEach(function(posSnapshot) {

                console.log('POSKEY', posSnapshot.key);

                if(posSnapshot.key != 'status') {

                    console.log(rngPos, incr, posSnapshot.val().state);

                    if(rngPos == incr && posSnapshot.val().state == 0) {

                        console.log('===');

                        resolve(posSnapshot.val().case);
                    }
                    else if(rngPos == incr && posSnapshot.val().state == 1) {

                        resolve('1');
                    }

                    incr ++;
                }
            });
        });

        print(dbResult);
    });
});

loopPromise.then(function(loopResult) {
    console.log(loopResult);
});

function print(tatarget) {
    console.log('TARGETOUT', tatarget);
    console.log('TARGETRESOLVE', tatarget);
}
```